# Trying to setup heroku app on my pc

Tags: heroku

I am going through the getting started guide with heroku and I hit a snag, cannot seem to access the remote database it connects but there is no database name. I have installed postgres sql 9.5 locally but attempting to push the local database I created fails also and when i run heroku pg:info it never responds.

I am going through the documentation but there is a lot of it, so hopefully some psql wizard will see this and go, oh this is what he is doing wrong and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have not "Created" the database. `rake db:create` - This needs to be done on Heroku's servers and your local machine.

Comment: Not true. In fact, `rake db:create` is forbidden. PG instances on Heroku must be provisioned from postgres.heroku.com or via the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite correct,I am not using ruby, one major caveat I did not notice initially is that I was not in the bash shell which might have been part of my problem, what i wound up doing was connecting to the postgresql remote instance from my local install using pgadmin and creating the table manually from there. I had to get the connection info which I obtained by using heroku pg:credentials DATABASE which gave me the info I needed to add the server in pgadmin, you do need to check ssl for that within the tool, and it helps to add the database name to restricted so you see only your database, not the whole 10 gazillion they have in production :) I hope this helps anyone else that has the same problem.

Thanks